# Django Log Formatting Not Being Applied

Tags: python, django, logging

I have added some loggers to my django application as instructed by the django website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#examples) but for whatever reason the logs are not applying the formats. Here is my logger setup:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s : module %(name)s : %(message)s'
    },
},
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    },
'require_debug_true': {
    '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    }
 },
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
    'file_request': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',   
        'filename': os.path.join(file_root, 'request' , 'wilkins_request.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*1, # 1MB
        'backupCount': 0,
        },    
    'file_backend': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],    
        'filename': os.path.join(file_root, 'backend' , 'wilkins_backend.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*6, # 6MB
        'backupCount': 0,
        },    
    'file_security': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',   
        'filename': os.path.join(file_root, 'backend' , 'wilkins_security.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*6, # 6MB
        'backupCount': 0,
        },    
    'file_migrations': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',   
        'filename': os.path.join(file_root, 'backend' , 'wilkins_migrations.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*1, # 1MB
        'backupCount': 0,
        },    
    'file_debug': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler', 
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],  
        'filename': os.path.join(file_root, 'debug' , 'wilkins.log'),
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*1, # 1MB
        'backupCount': 0,
        },    
 },
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file_request'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': True,
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    'django.security': {
        'handlers': ['file_security'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['file_backend'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    'django.db.backends.schema': {
        'handlers': ['file_migrations'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    'wilkins': {
        'handlers': ['file_debug'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
        'formatter': 'simple'
        },
}
```

}

But my output looks like this:

(from the wilkins_request.log)

```
Not Found: /accounts/login9
Not Found: /accounts/login9
Not Found: /accounts/login9
Not Found: /l
Not Found: /l
Not Found: /l
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

(and from wilkins.log)

```
Made it to the Projects view.
Made it to the Projects view.
Made it to the Projects view.
Made it to the Projects view.
```

I am at a total loss as to why this is happening. I am using stock Django 1.7, so I have not changed any code paths or settings in django except for this logging variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Formatters apply to handlers, not to loggers. Move those `formatter:` lines to the handler dicts and things should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't get that right in my config. I knew it was dumb and small.